# How to Show/Hide "Share this buttons html" on desired routes added in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am making changes in an existing Angular application. 
I have the requirement to hide the "Share this buttons" on certain routes. This "Share" module  appears on the  left side of the browser windows  and is added in the application in `index.html` file with a link tag in head as below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5c6992d57056550011c4a534&product=inline-share-buttons"
async="async"></script>
```

Problem is that this module is added outside the angular application and this html is not being added from angular application.
Is there any way I can remove or hide the "Share This" div on certain routes with JavaScript or Typescript?

[image: Share this html that appears on every route]

Comment: Does this content (button bar) get loaded in a separate iframe ?

Comment: This is being added as a div but above that div I can see an iframe above it on inspecting the elements with div tools.

Comment: You need to create a custom directive to load the script (NOT using script tag in index) and wrap the loaded content. On subscribing to router events in the directive you can control the visibility of the div.

Comment: @ashish.gd, Is there any example that i can fallow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element is loaded ascynchronously and outside the angular framework you have to access javascript's `window` or `document` objects and dynamically add custom css to the iframe you want to hide.

To access document you can do something like this:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export class SomeClass {

  window: any;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
     this.window = this.document.defaultView;
  }

  check() {
    console.log(this.document);
    console.log(this.window);
  }

}
```

after accessing the window and document you can dynamically add css to hide an element:

```
document.getElementById("your_iframe_id").style.display = "none";
```

If the iframe does not have an id you can use other methods in `document` like `getElementsByTagName("iframe")` to get all iframes in your page, or something similar

Comment: Solved this a long time ago, but since i have used the similar approach so I mark your answer as accepted.